# unvoted-on comments look voted-on

Tags: bug, comments, meta, voting, display

Upvoted and non-upvoted comments on Mi Yodeya Meta look the same to me on mobile. For example, the following screenshot shows three comments: one by the person who took the screenshot, one he had upvoted, and one he had not; the latter two have the same-looking voting arrow.

[image: a screenshot, as described above]

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Mi A1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.99 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Weird.  On my Android phone this doesn't happen, but my comment-upvote markers are black not orange (links are still orange), so there's obviously some other difference between our environments. What browser are you using?  I see Mozilla, AppleWebKit, and Safari all in that user-agent string but don't really know how to read it.

Comment: @mon Nor do I. It's Chrome.

Comment: [I am unable to reproduce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkIeR.jpg) Do you have a screenshot of full-site view that shows them differently?

Comment: Huh -- and Chrome is what I use, too.  Of course, could be different Chrome versions, different Android versions, some unrelated-seeming setting... I hope we can characterize this so it can be fixed.

Comment: [Reported on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314862/comment-upvote-triangle-always-appears-upvoted) with some people able to reproduce.

Comment: @Alex, "full site" view shows the non-upvoted grey and the upvoted black (or very dark grey?). I'm not sure what good a screenshot will do.

Comment: The problem does not manifest itself for me on Meta SE or on Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @msh210 The bug reported there was also referring to a different site.

Comment: Not consistently reproducible for me even on Meta MY.